# Graph with minimum degree $\ge 3$ and exact $1$ hamilton circuit

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Enumerating the graphs upto $9$ vertices and the cubic connected graphs upto $18$
 vertices, I did not find a graph with minimum degree $\ge 3$ and exact $1$
 hamilton circuit.

- Is there a graph with this property ?
- If yes, which one is the smallest ?

Comment: A beautiful result due to Andrew Thomason states that if every vertex of a graph has odd degree, then every edge is contained in an even number of Hamiltonian cycles. So you certainly won't find what you're looking for amongst the cubic graphs.

Comment: A very nice partial result!